# struct definition and initialization

Tags: c, static, initialization

I saw a piece of code

```
static struct {
    u32 xxx;
    struct {
        u32 xxx;
        u32 xxx;
        u32 xxx;
    } xxx[xxx+1];
 } xxx = {0};
```

Does it mean we intialize all fields as 0?

Comment: What does your C book say? We are not a tutoring site for code you found somewhere on your backyard.

Comment: A compilable example would be better. You can't name all the members `xxx`, and there's no type called `u32` unless you define it yourself or include a header that does so.

Comment: Succinctly "yes", but you should go read a text book to find out more.